# What is the LTI token timeout variable?

Tags: authentication, desire2learn, lti

We are getting the following error:

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> D2L.WS.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Expired authentication token
  at D2L.WS.Security.Authentication.TokenAuthenticator.AuthententicateHeader(Int64 orgId, RequestHeaderInfo headerInfo)
  at D2L.WS.Implementation.SoapHeaderServiceBase`1.set_RequestHeader(RequestHeaderInfo value)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
            at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:446)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)

We are getting the token using LTIAuthenticationTokenService.authenticate() and we re-use it for multiple, consecutive web-service calls. For this reason, we cache the token for 2 minutes, which until now had worked on all our other customer's servers.

Is there a DOME variable or configuration setting that controls how long the authentication token is valid?

Answer (score 1):

There are DOME configuration variables that control the lifetime of access tokens, and I believe that these apply to D2LWS tokens. If these calls were working with your back-end service before, and are not now, then this may be exposing either a mis-configuration of your LMS, or a regression defect introduced with a service pack to your service. In either case, your best bet is to contact D2L's [support desk](http://helpdesk.desire2learn.com/) through either your organization's approved support contact, or your account or partner manager -- many of the DOME configuration variables are only modifiable by D2L themselves, and they can more likely assist your particular case to help determine if this is a mis-configuration or a defect.

Answer (score 1):

D2L LMS DOME variables `d2l.Security.WebService.MaxUsageCount` and `d2l.Security.WebService.TokenLifetime` (seconds) control this behaviour